# Why the assigned action is done before clicking the button in pycharm ?(language- python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a root window by using pycharm. I added a button widget which does not work properly. When I run the program it executes the action (action that is assigned for that button) before clicking on the button.
code:-

````
   from tkinter import messagebox


   def buttontapped():

       messagebox._show("Message", "Hello World")


   root = Tk()


   label1 = Label(root, text="Nish")

   label1.pack()

   Button(root, text="Message", command=buttontapped()).pack()

   root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: we cant exactly help you if you dont post the code with the error; however, i suspect you called the function in the line where you bind it to the button

Comment: Please show the code. It's probably related to this, however: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: I'm new so...here's the code- from tkinter import * from tkinter import messagebox def buttonTapped(): messagebox._show("Message", "Hello World") root = Tk() label1 = Label(root, text="Nish") label1.pack() Button(root, text="Message", COMMAND=buttonTapped()).pack() root.mainloop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not shared the code, i can only guess what could be causing the problem.
However, this sounds like a common mistake of including parenthesis in the bind method: `button.bind('<event>',function())`
This calls the function immediately and binds the return value instead of the function.
If this is the problem, the solution is to remove the parenthesis.

Comment: I'm new so...here's the code-     from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def buttonTapped():
    messagebox._show("Message", "Hello World")


root = Tk()


label1 = Label(root, text="Nish")
label1.pack()

Button(root, text="Message", COMMAND=buttonTapped()).pack()

root.mainloop()

Comment: @NishchayRaj it was what i said; change `COMMAND=buttonTapped()` to `COMMAND=buttonTapped`

Comment: I have tried this but it shows-    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Nish/Practice/Root.py", line 15, in <module>
    Button(root, text="Message", COMMAND=buttonTapped).pack()
  File "D:\Users\NISH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2366, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "D:\Users\NISH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-COMMAND"

Comment: oh, the correct parameter name is `command`; in python variable names are case-sensitive

Comment: can you edit the question with your code between backticks, like \`\`\`this\`\`\`?

Comment: Done!! and sorry for late editing. Today was my last exam.

Comment: no, you have to use backticks(\`), not quotes(' or ") so it looks like `this` and not like '''this'''

Comment: you see the line with `command=buttontapped()`? you are calling the function immediately and giving whatever buttontapped() returns as the function to be called when the button is clicked; change it to `command=buttontapped` so are giving the function buttontapped to be called *when the button is clicked*

Comment: Thanks brother now it works properly :) . And thanks for giving this time.

Comment: no problem; in the future, you may want to search your problem on other sites before opening a question on Stack Overflow.